# Reverse order of every other character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a project where the data I'm receiving is being given to me in a messed up order. I need every 2 characters to switch places in a string. Currently I have the below code, but it is ungodly slow in a function or stored procedure. Any help would be appreciated.

Ex: `FK741 OCEV` needs to be `KF47 1COVE`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[UnscrambleData] 
(
    @scrambled varchar(50) 
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @unscrambled varchar(50)
    Declare @temp1 varchar(1)
    DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
    Declare @cnt_Total INT =len(@scrambled)

    WHILE @cnt < = @cnt_total
       if((@cnt%2)=0)
       begin 
             set @unscrambled=CONCAT( @unscrambled,SUBSTRING(@scrambled, @cnt, 1),@temp1)
             set @temp1=''
       end
   else if (@cnt_Total%2<>0 and @cnt_Total-@cnt<2)
       begin
              set @unscrambled=CONCAT( @unscrambled,SUBSTRING(@scrambled, @cnt, 1))
       end
   else
       begin
             set @temp1= SUBSTRING(@scrambled, @cnt, 1)
       end
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

    RETURN @unscrambled;
END
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Why can;t you just fix the broken data once. It won;t matter if was fixed using a slow or fast function.

Comment: Don't you think you should fix the way those strings comes? Or you 're going to do string manipulation under the db forever? (which is bad idea)

Comment: You should be able to do the manipulation in pairs instead of one at a time.  count up by 2 instead of 1.  Change a few other things . . .

Comment: I dont have control of how the data is being sent, and the way the machine is transmitting the data, i unfortunately have to do it sql side. The problem is that i cant think of a more efficient way to run this.

Comment: so how slow is slow?  Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza currently it takes around 20-25 minutes to run. This is going to need to run almost continuously.

Comment: Is the length of string an even number? Or how you handle odd lengths?

Comment: @Angesehen First of all you need to get ride of the `WHILE` loop and think of a set-based solution.

Comment: 20  25 for how many rows ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 1 row, and they will always be even lengths.

Comment: @Sami and yes i agree but i cannot think of a way to do this without using a while loop.

Comment: what version of sql server are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that as

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(REVERSE(V), '')
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('FK741 OCEV')
) T(Str) CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Str, Number-1, 2)
  FROM Master..spt_values --Tally table
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(Str)
        AND Number % 2 = 0
) TT(V)
```

**Returns:**

```
KF47 1COVE
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd7e9f1eeaa3016e49f582f7d704b1a3)**</kbd>

If you have more than one string then

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(REVERSE(V), '')
FROM
(
  VALUES
  (1, 'FK741 OCEV'),
  (2, 'ABC DEF GH'),
  (3, 'THIRD STRING')
) T(Id, Str) CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Str, Number-1, 2)
  FROM Master..spt_values
  WHERE [Type] = 'P'
        AND Number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(Str)
        AND Number % 2 = 0
) TT(V)
GROUP BY T.Id;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a set-based solution, you can use a loop that works quicker than your current solution (at least based on my test):

```
DECLARE @scrambled VARCHAR(50) = 'FK741 OCEV';
DECLARE @test_unscrambled VARCHAR(50) = 'KF47 1COVE';
DECLARE @unscrambled VARCHAR(50) = '';

DECLARE @idx INT = 1;
DECLARE @this_char CHAR(1), @next_char CHAR(1);

WHILE @idx <= LEN(@scrambled)
BEGIN
    SET @this_char = SUBSTRING(@scrambled, @idx, 1);
    SET @next_char = SUBSTRING(@scrambled, @idx + 1, 1);
    SET @unscrambled = @unscrambled + @next_char + @this_char;

    SET @idx = @idx + 2;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/UJDI70861)**

First convert string into rows. Then change the position and put back together

```
with cte as (
      select cast('FK741 OCEV' as varchar(max)) as str, 
             cast(NULL as varchar(max)) as letter, 
             0 as lev, 
             0 as i
      union all
      select substring(str, 2, len(str)), left(str, 1), lev + 1, i + 1 
      from cte
      where str <> ''
    ),
flip as (    
    select letter, CASE WHEN I % 2 > 0 THEN I + 1
                        ELSE I - 1
                   END as I
    from cte
    where lev > 0
),
assembly (scramble) as (
    SELECT letter + ',' AS [text()] 
    FROM flip         
    ORDER BY i
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)    
SELECT replace ( scramble, ',', '') as scramble
FROM assembly
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    scramble
1   KF47 1COVE
```

Comment: What's the need to `CAST()` the string to `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

Comment: @Sami You need define the type to make sure the recursive doesn't get a `Types doesnt match ` Error

Comment: [`select 'FK741 OCEV' as str, '' as letter`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0dcd43d69f6268fd5bed41e5ce16d5e1)

Comment: You can try on the sql demo. remove the cast and you will see the error

Comment: And you can try the given demo ^ @Juan Carlos Oropeza :)

Comment: mm your demo give me the same error `Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "letter" of recursive query "cte".`

Comment: Check it again, and see the changes.

Comment: So what is the difference, why yours doesnt get error?

Answer (score 1):

@sami posted the only high-performing set-based solution; that's the one to go with.

You can, however, cheat and use [ngrams8K]. It will be very fast as well and with simplified code.[1](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams).

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'FK741 OCEV';

SELECT NewString = 
(
  SELECT   REVERSE(ng.token) 
  FROM     dbo.ngrams8k(@string,2) AS ng
  WHERE    ng.position%2=1
  ORDER BY ng.position
  FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

**Returns:** KF47 1COVE

**Against a table:**

```
WITH SampleData AS 
  (SELECT TOP (10) OldString=STUFF(LEFT(NEWID(),7),5,0,' ') FROM sys.all_columns)
SELECT s.OldString, f.NewString
FROM   SampleData AS s
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT   REVERSE(ng.token) 
  FROM     dbo.ngrams8k(s.OldString,2) AS ng
  WHERE    ng.position%2=1
  ORDER BY ng.position
  FOR XML PATH('')
) AS f(NewString);
```

**Returns:**

```
OldString  NewString
---------- ----------
D82E EDE   8DE2E ED
655C E83   56C5E 38
307D 62B   03D76 B2
F485 83A   4F588 A3
80DF ABB   08FDA BB
EC97 EB3   CE79E 3B
7279 DE6   2797D 6E
06A8 35B   608A3 B5
8CBD D1E   C8DBD E1
D17B 3A0   1DB73 0A
```